# PHP mcrypt error: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mcrypt'

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp, mcrypt

I extracted mcrypt to C:\xampp\php\ext,
updated the php.ini with extension=php_mcrypt,
rebooted the Apache server,
and steel I get: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mcrypt' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt...
Also I cant see the module with php -m

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the module?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero I think so, I'm using php 8.2.0, with mcrypt 7.4 (tried both ts and nts)

Comment: Is there version 8.2 of mcrypt?

Comment: Check here https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero yes but it's not available on dll

Answer (score 0):

In order to install PHP extensions on Windows you either need to download precompiled DLL from PECL, or compile the code yourself.

As of writing this answer precompiled DLLs for [mcrypt](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) are only available for version 1.0.4 and older. Newest release, version 1.0.5 which is compatible with PHP 8.2.0 only has source code listed, which means you'll have to compile it yourself: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

**Alternatively, you might want to try to use this polyfill library instead**: https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat